VS code not auto sugggesting MUI component imports
I have this problem where before I was able to just click suggested import by VS code with MUI components, but now I am not able to do it anymore, I think I modified my settings accidentally. Could you guys help me.

I am expecting to, when I type in MUi components VS code will auto suggest and will just click it for auto importing.

Please provide any kind of extension information you can or whatever the settings were... Honestly VS Code is just a text editor and does not have any centralized source of truth on any autocompletion stuff, what settings were you screwing with (reading documentation is good)
